# AngularJS - Actual values not being passed from drop down

Tags: angularjs

**In my html:**

[image]

```
<li data-ng-repeat="module in sbVM.partialModules" data-ng-click="sbVM.selectModule('{{module.id}}', '{{module.name}}')">{{module.name}}</li>
```

**Compiled HTML:**

[image]

**In my code behind:**

```
    sbVM.selectModule = function (id, name) {
        sbVM.selectedModuleId = id;
        sbVM.selectedModule = name;
        activate(sbVM.selectedModuleId);
    };
```

**In Chrome debugger:**

[image]

**And I get this error:**

[image]

**When the values are hard coded in the html, everything is fine:**

```
<li class="selectModule" data-ng-click="sbVM.selectModule('1', 'Personal Module')"></li>
<li class="selectModule" data-ng-click="sbVM.selectModule('2', 'Website Module')"></li>
<li class="selectModule" data-ng-click="sbVM.selectModule('3', 'Commerce Module')"></li>
<li class="selectModule" data-ng-click="sbVM.selectModule('4', 'Super Admin Module')"></li>
```

But that obviously is not what I want. As you can see from the debugger, the actual values are not being passed, only the controller's property names. Can anyone explain the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <li data-ng-repeat="module in sbVM.partialModules" 
     data-ng-click="sbVM.selectModule(module.id, module.name)">
   {{module.name}}
   </li>
```

ng-click expect an expression.